# Laravel images from storage doesn't display correct with www prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two domains - first with www prefix, second without prefix:

1. http://www.example_one.com/
2. http://example_two.com/

Images, documents etc from storage directory works only on domain: 2)
but when I try to redirect domain 1) - images, documents etc doesn't display correct. I changed APP_URL in .env but still nothing.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks you so much

Comment: Is this the same app?

Comment: ye only website url is other

Comment: did you try `config:clear`?

Comment: yes, all artisan commands with :clear

Comment: @Giacomo check the console if it has any CORS middleware problems

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed only 404 errors (file doesn't exist)

Comment: @Giacomo can you edit and add a URL example please, and are you trying access the storage with out linking it first?